# Lost BCH before it came out

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash

I had around 20 BTC on my blockchain.info when bitcoin-cash forked and so after the fork I exported my seed and pasted it into electro-cash in order to receive my BCH (done it before and it worked) but when i synced it I was greeted by zero balance with a ton of transactions from 2016/09 to 2017/07 so there is no history after the fork nor the BCH

Comment: Can you provide some more detail, such as a receiving address that you expected to hold coins at the time of the fork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is electron cash which uses a different seed format to other wallets. First, to be safe, move your BTC from it's current wallet to a new wallet,

Then put that seed you tried to put in to Electron Cash in to a different wallet like 'Bitcoin.com wallet

Answer (score 0):

If you're indeed using electron-cash you should not have a transaction history. Are you sure you're not using electrum ?